# AS3: How do I automate declaring multiple objects

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to initialize and populate multiple objects along with their related properies automatically.

Basically I have a 32x32 grid and for each position on the grid I would like to assign an object with multiple properties that can be referenced later.

A 32x32 grid has 1024 positions on it and I really don't want to have to write up that many variable declarations manually. I have the array set up in a separate class file which allows me to assign a variable to a grid position: *gridPos.put(x, y, object.property);*

I have also set up a pair of for loops which will populate the objects with default starting data.

Now what I need to do is get it to declare the objects for me with unique names and  then populate them all with the starting data. These objects need to be accessible from other parts of the code (I tried to declare them as public var *gridPosTile[h] : Object = new Object;* but declaring it as 'public' it gave me an error saying it *"1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package."*)

*Also, I know [h] is not right but it was kinda how I saw it working in my head... please illuminate me :)

Many Thanks

```
    public function gridPosTilePopulate():void
    {

        var g: int = 40;
        var h: int = 1;

        for(var i:int = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            var v: int = 40;

            g += 40;

            for(var q:int = 0; q < 32; q++)
            {
                var gridPosTile[h] : Object = new Object;

                gridPos.put(i, q, gridPosTile[h]);

                gridPosTile[h].xPos = (v + 40));
                gridPosTile[h].yPos = (g + 40));
                gridPosTile[h].p1Set = false);
                gridPosTile[h].p2Set = false);
                gridPosTile[h].m1Set = false);
                gridPosTile[h].m2Set = false);
                gridPosTile[h].m3Set = false);
                gridPosTile[h].m4Set = false);
                gridPosTile[h].coinSet = false);
                gridPosTile[h].powerupSet = false);

                v += 40;
                h++;


            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your full class so I can not tell you why you got the 1114 error.
I would start with adding a a property to your class to store the gridPosTitle objects.
You should use an array collection or a vector. In my example I will use an arrayCollection.
This storage collection will allow you easy reference to all of the tiles you have created.
To add a dynamic name property all you need to do is use bracket notation.
And lastly remove all reference to "h" since it is not needed except to name the object.

```
package com.example{
    public class SomeClassName{

      // storage var for future use.
      public var tileStorage:ArrayColelction
      public function gridPosTilePopulate():void
      {
        tileStorage = new ArrayCollection()

        var g: int = 40;
        var h: int = 1;

        for(var i:int = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            var v: int = 40;

            g += 40;

            for(var q:int = 0; q < 32; q++)
            {
                var gridPosTile : Object = new Object;

                gridPos.put(i, q, gridPosTile);

                gridPosTile.xPos = (v + 40));
                gridPosTile.yPos = (g + 40));
                gridPosTile.p1Set = false);
                gridPosTile.p2Set = false);
                gridPosTile.m1Set = false);
                gridPosTile.m2Set = false);
                gridPosTile.m3Set = false);
                gridPosTile.m4Set = false);
                gridPosTile.coinSet = false);
                gridPosTile.powerupSet = false);

                v += 40;
                h++;
                // here we add the name property
                // try to never use keywords on dynamic classes since sometimes they may already be used
                gridPosTile.myName = "tile_" + h;
                tileStorage.additem(gridPosTile)

            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Also I would create a custom class for gridPosTile that holds all the properties as that will give you a solid reference to the object and a centralized class you can make changes in.

Comment: Hi, Thanks I'm going to give that a go :)  the ArrayCollection doesn't seem to be recognised? From what I can see this is part of the FLEX framework, framework.swc which apparently I can just copy to my project folder and include but I don't know where to find the file so I can copy it?